# How to search/filter by month or year from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to filter the report based on month or year using dropdown search button.
I'm having problem because the data for month that being search cannot be displayed.

Here are some codes that I've tried:

```
if(!empty($_POST['search'])){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM complain
        WHERE MONTH(timeComplain)='".$_POST['search']."'";
  $query = $conn -> query($sql);
  $row = $query -> fetch_assoc();
}
```

```
<form action="report.php" method="post">
  <div class="w3-left">
    <select name="search" class="w3-select" value="">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
   <input type="submit" id="search" value="Filter">              
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the code that displays the result?

Comment: You should also execute the query before any results are displayed: `$query->execute();` this should work if your using a sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to execute the query.
Use `PDO` instead.
Your PHP code should look like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['search'])){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM complain WHERE MONTH(timeComplain)= :month";
  $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $params = array(':month' => $_POST['search']);
  $query->execute($params);
  $row = $query->fetch();
  // then you can do "echo $row['']"
}
```

You should execute the query before any results are received.
Your `$conn` should look like this:

```
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

try { $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", 
$username, $password, $options); } 
catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());} 
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```